# display image flag once when variable appear multiple times in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php with mysql and have developed a code element that queries a record set of images. The images that are associated with my users are flagged as different image types and on my web page I want to display a flag just once if the image type is present one or more times in the record set. At the moment if I use the following code the flag appears as many times as the image type appears in the record set. Can someone advise how I limit the echo statement to be displayed once only?

```
if 
($image_type==6)
{
echo "<a href=\"form2.php?pid=$itemID\"><img src=\"images/flag.png\" width=\"120\"  height=\"20\" border=\"0\" /></a><br />";
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: The best will be to review your SQL query. Can you show us more code? (especially the loop)

Answer (score 0):

Either filter at the SQL level so a particular flag value only shows up once in the results, or keep track of displayed flags in PHP and only display them if not previous displayed, e.g.

```
$shown_flags = array();

while(... fetch results from data...) {
   if (!isset($shown_flags[$image_type]))
          ... display flag
          $shown_flags[$image_type] = true;
   }
}
```